# What NICs does -P OUTPUT ACCEPT affect?

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables

If I have two NICs; `eth0` and `eth1`.

Does this rule then allow all outgoing traffic on all NICs?

```
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

Or do I have to

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
```

?

Comment: iptable rules work as a list and are evaluated in order on a per packet basis, not per interface. the -P rule is the default rule if no others match so affects any packets that get to the end of the list unmatched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-P` flag to iptables sets policies on the built-in chains.  That is, they set the default disposition for packets which make it all the way through a built-in chain without matching a single dispositive rule.

If you only have two NICs (`eth0`, `eth1`), and no other rules in your OUTPUT chain, there is no difference between the two setups you posted above.

Comment: Would that also make `iptables -A INPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT` obsolete?

Comment: Setting the policy to ACCEPT means that **any** packet that matches no dispositive rule will be ACCEPTed, so yes, it does make that rule obsolete.